# NETWORK SERVICE user cannot read certificate windows server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, x509certificate, azure-service-fabric

I have a local service running on my windows 2012 server machine. It is a azure service fabric cluster with one node, but this shouldn't matter for this problem.

The service runs under the "NETWORK SERVICE: user, and has code that accesses a certificate stored on local machine. The code that finds the certificate using [X509Certificate2Collection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The exception is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not successfully acquire access token
>   using thumbprints: 80CEA40A62FFA0116FCB40B7B5985ADCD3E5AC39

When I execute the same Find function with same parameters locally as admin user, it works.

I have tried explicitly granting the NETWORK SERVICE user read permission on the certificate, but this did not solve it.

I have also tried executing code locally under NETWORK SERVICE user context (not as deployed local service, but local executable code snippet) that gets a certificate, and this works, which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the issue is that the network service doesn't have access to the private key. I use the following code to set the permission, after importing the certificates to my own store with me having access to the private keys

```
Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -FilePath "path to the pfx file"
$certs = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My

Foreach ($cert in $certs)
{
 # Specify the user, the permissions and the permission type
 $permission = "Network Service","FullControl","Allow"
 $accessRule = New-Object -TypeName 
 System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission

 # Location of the machine related keys
 $keyPath = Join-Path -Path $env:ProgramData -ChildPath "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"
 $keyName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
 $keyFullPath = Join-Path -Path $keyPath -ChildPath $keyName

 # Get the current acl of the private key
 $acl = (Get-Item $keyFullPath).GetAccessControl('Access')

 # Add the new ace to the acl of the private key
 $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)

 # Write back the new acl
 Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath -AclObject $acl -ErrorAction Stop

 # Observe the access rights currently assigned to this certificate.
 get-acl $keyFullPath| fl
 }
```

Comment: I have given permission to the private key via windows MMC certificate manager (that's what I meant by "giving the user read permission on the certificate") but I'll try the script

Comment: Any clue on how to find which .pfx file is associate with my cert?

Comment: if you don't have the original, be logged in as a user that has access to the private key and then export it with the private key to a pfx :)